# TCPDF HTML Tags <>Confusion

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF for a some assessments that I am creating for my elementary students.  Everything worked fine until I got to the greater and less than part.  When ever I wanted to type in the greater symbol like this <, it would't come out thinking it was going to be an html tag.  I am wondering if there is a way to fix that confusion.  Here is a sample of the code so that you may understand:

```
 <?php $html .= 'a. < <br />
    b. > <br />
    c. = <br />
    d. + ';          


    // output the HTML content
      $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); ?>
```

What that is displaying is this:

a. 
b. > 
c. = 
d. +

How can I fix this issue?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible you could use the [encoded values](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

Comment: That's a strange problem; if it proves to be true, I'd suggest reporting it as a bug to the TCPDF developers. An HTML parser should interpret a space after the `<` as leaving it as the plaintext entity.

Comment: For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaVmz/

Comment: the encoded values &#60; worked.  The only thing is that I would have to change all of the ones I have created in my database which is over 150 of them.  Is there a way where tcpdf recognizes that its a symbol instead of a tag.  Let me know.  if not so that I can start working on all on them LOL.

Comment: I don't know; I would have imagined it would by default. If you leave it as the entity (not the encoding), but remove the trailing `<br/>`, does it display correctly?

Comment: If you need to as well, you could `$yourmarkup = str_replace('< ', '&#60', $yourmarkup);` if a trailing space always follows, which I would think you could do without manually changing the affected rows, or run a script to update them. Note, no html parser should interpret `< ` with a space following as an opening to a tag.

Comment: Let me try it out and I will let you know.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This is somewhat related, with the TCPDF devs saying it's not a bug since the `<` should be escaped (encoded) to be valid HTML: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3041923&group_id=128076&atid=710532

Comment: You could possibly use [HTML Purifier](http://bit.ly/u8w7hF)  (link with demo of your code from above) to modify your content, which seems to fix it nicely ([which you can download](http://htmlpurifier.org/download) and use before outputting to PDF).

Comment: Wow that worked!  I am going to try that.  Thank for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

- `<` must be escaped as `&lt;`
- `>` must be escaped as `&gt;`

This is how HTML works (not specific to TCPDF parser).